# Regular expression to extract lines between two strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have text with SAS code in it. Essentially it is SQL query wrapped between

```
    PROC SQL;
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    QUIT;
```

I am trying to extract SQL in between as a single match.

This is how my text file looks like

```
***logic 1***
proc sql;
 create table Combined as
  select t1.name, t2.units
  from mdweop.candy_customers_azim_056 as t1
  inner join mdweop.candy_sales_history_set  t2 on (t1.custid = t2.ORIGTN_ACCT_NO);
quit;

***logic 2***
PROC SQL;
 CREATE TABLE COMBINED AS
  SELECT T1.RPOG_HMDA_CODES, T2.RSN_DECL1_C
  FROM MDWEOP.CANDY_CUSTOMERS AS T1
  INNER JOIN MDWEOP.CANDY_SALES_HISTORY AS T2
    ON (T1.CUSTID = T2.ACA_MISC_Z03HMDA_BV);
QUIT;

***logic 3***
PROC SQL;
 CREATE TABLE COMBINED AS
  SELECT T1.RRG_PRPS_CODES, T2.RSN_DECL1_C
  FROM MDWEOP.CANDY_CUSTOMERS AS T1
  INNER JOIN MDWEOP.CANDY_SALES_HISTORY AS T2
    ON (T1.CUSTID = T2.ACA_MISC_Z03HMDA_BV);
QUIT;
```

I tried this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/xC7qJ2/2) but its finding each line as single individual match.

Ideally if i want to extract each SQL query from the text file

Any leads are well appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I've a doubt that this will solve your real problem to get SQL or not?**, But I've posted this answer as per your regex demo.

```js
const regex = /START-OF-FIELDS[\r\n]+(.*)[\n\r]+(.*)[\n\r](.*)[\n\r]END-OF-FIELDS/img;
const str = `START-OF-FIELDS
Line A
Line B
Line C
END-OF-FIELDS`;
let m;
const sql_lines = []
while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }

  // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
  m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
    if (groupIndex > 0) {
      sql_lines.push(match);
    }
  });
}

console.log(sql_lines)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the `s` modifier to your regex which allows the `.` character to also match newlines, and `i` for matching case variation. Also use non-capturing groups for the prefix and suffix:

```
/^(?:START\-OF\-FIELDS)(.*)(?:END\-OF\-FIELDS)$/mgsi
```

[See it in action here](https://regex101.com/r/xC7qJ2/44)